# Azure RM Template. Execute .ps1 script after deployment is complete

Tags: azure

I'd like to execute a custom .ps1 script as soon as my servers are deployed. All Azure docs and examples describes how to install something with DSC (like natively supported IIS), but how do I execute PowerShell script with ARM template, instead of stating configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom script extension to run a PowerShell script. you will be able to call the custom script as part of your ARM Template

http://blog.fullscale180.com/azure-arm-templates-tips-and-tricks-5-custom-script-extension-workaround-i-cannot-add-another-extension-to-a-vm-to-run-a-script-on-the-last-node-of-the-cluster/